# Fake Animate a single image file in IOS possible?

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-animation

Over the years software has been introduced to give a fake animation effect to a single photo image so the image appears moving as in an animated gif. I'm not talking about rotation or translation or animated gifs from multiple photos but rather the mimicking of video or Live Photos from a single photo by automagically perturbing the layers or pixels. [After Effects, for example, lets you do this](https://nofilmschool.com/2013/11/tutorial-how-to-animate-still-photos-in-after-effects).

Does anyone know if something like this is possible with IOS libraries such core animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in motion effect of UIView. check UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.